# Effectively Firing a multiple query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I was practicing drawing graphs on various statistics for the  purpose of data analysis. But I am not able to figure out an efficient way to fire multiple **mysql** query at the back-end.

I am trying to draw **Period** Vs **No of Visitors** graph.
Please Note: Period here refers to week,month,3 months,6 months,1 year,2 years.
Period will be selected by the user from the  select box.
For example: When User selects 3 week, I need to construct No of Visitors per 3 week graph.
[image]

My DataBase Contains Two Column: For each of the site hit, it records:

(1) **timestamp** and

(2)**user ID**.

If I fire query multiple times for each select option, then performance would be quite poor.So, How to do it efficiently?

UPD:
When User Select stats per 3 month:

Then I am firing mysql query as:

```
Select count(*) From stats_tab WHERE timestamp BETWEEN JAN  AND MAR;
Select count(*) From stats_tab WHERE timestamp BETWEEN APR AND JUN;
Select count(*) From stats_tab WHERE timestamp BETWEEN JUL AND SEP;
............
```

Each count returned from each of the query will be the y-axis value for my graph

When User Select stats per year:
Then I am firing mysql query as:

```
    Select count(*) From stats_tab WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 2009 AND 2010;
    Select count(*) From stats_tab WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 2010 AND 2011;
    Select count(*) From stats_tab WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 2011 AND 2012;
    ............
```

Comment: why do you need more than a one query for the period selected?

Comment: Without seeing queries that you're firing right now we can't help you

Comment: you can combine those queries in to one, group by month or year and probably gets the counts in the query as well

Comment: i suggest opening a new question on how to do a single query to get the data, showing the table structure ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hit database with multiple queries. Get all your values with one query appropriately applying `GROUP BY` and `WHERE`

```sql
SELECT YEAR(timestamp) year, COUNT(*) total
  FROM stats_tab 
 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 3 YEAR AND NOW()
 GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp);

SELECT MONTH(timestamp) month, COUNT(*) total
  FROM stats_tab 
 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH AND NOW()
 GROUP BY MONTH(timestamp);

SELECT DAY(timestamp) day, COUNT(*) total
  FROM stats_tab 
 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND NOW()
 GROUP BY DAY(timestamp);
```

Sample output:

```
| YEAR | TOTAL |
----------------
| 2011 |     2 |
| 2012 |     1 |
| 2013 |     9 |

| MONTH | TOTAL |
-----------------
|     2 |     1 |
|     3 |     2 |
|     5 |     1 |

| DAY | TOTAL |
---------------
|  20 |     1 |
|  21 |     1 |
|  22 |     1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edc71/2)** demo